# How to disable refresh page after using pop out this form

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am working on MScrm 365 on-premise there is a new feature **pop out this form** after clicking this button the form is out but the page is refreshed to a grid, is there an option to disable this refresh?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is by product design, once you pop-out the record, the user navigate away to the grid/list page in main window.

You can implement a custom button logic and implement your need instead of rigging the product behavior which is unsupported and will break in future releases.